# Is 3ds Max scriptable in C++ or C# instead of Python?

Tags: 3dsmax

3DS Max offers a Python API, but that API is built on top of SWiG/CPython. I'm curious, is it possible to script 3DS MAX using C++ or C#, given that SWiG is simply a wrapper for (predumably) C/C++ API?

Comment: I use to program plugins using C++ for 3ds Max, and I remember there was a SDK for C# some years ago (I think). With that said, it's not the same as scripting. You can do more, but the learning curve is steeper.

Comment: @Reactgular what I like with scripting is you can just run it without having to go through some complicated process. then again I don't mind compiling stuff if I get the same result. Python implementation of 3ds is *awful*, there's no typing, I get no code completion in PyCharm (because it's SWiG generated), it's an unusable mess

Comment: Back when I did scripting we used MaxScript. That was an unusable mess..... lol

Comment: @Reactgular yes, that's even worse.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to program in C++, why not use the SDK?  There is also .NET exposure described [here](https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2019/ENU/?guid=__developer_3ds_max__net_sdk_html).  But note the SDK samples are written in C++ generally, so you'll find more support and information there.

The SDK is a separate option, when installing 3ds Max, click "Install Tools & Utilities" instead of the regular install button.  Documentation is [here](https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2019/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_index_html).